# Proof that two sub-sequences limits are the same $\iff$ sequence converges

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

I'm trying to proof that if $(b_n)$ is a sequence s.t. sequences $(b_{2n})$ and $(b_{2n+1})$ converges to $a$ and $b$ then $a=b\iff (b_n)$ is convergence.

---

[$\implies$] if $a=b$ then $\exists N_1,N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|b_{2n}-a|\lt\epsilon/2$ for $n\gt N_1$ and $|b_{2n+1}-b|\lt\epsilon/2$ for $n\gt N_2$. Let $N:=max\{N_1,N_2\}$. For $n\gt N$ we have $|b_{2n}-a|\lt\epsilon/2$ and $|b_{2n+1}-b|\lt\epsilon/2$. Now by triangle inequality $b-a=|b-a|=|(b_{2n+1}-b)-(b_{2n}-a)|\le|b_{2n+1}|+|b_{2n}|=|b_n|\lt\epsilon$

[$\impliedby$] if $(b_n)$ is convergent then $\forall\epsilon\gt0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|b_n-a|\lt\epsilon \forall n\gt N$. We know that $n_i\gt N$ for $i\gt N$. We deduce $|b_{ni}-a|\lt\epsilon\forall i\gt N$. Therefore $(b_{ni})\rightarrow a$. This shows that all sub-sequences of the sequence $(b_n)\rightarrow a$. So if $(b_{2n})\rightarrow a$ and $(b_{2n+1})\rightarrow b$ then $a=b$.

---

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you prove in $\implies$? You get $b-a < \epsilon$? But you need that $(b_n)_n$ converges?

Comment: ok, my thinking is that $\le|b_{2n+1}||+|b_{2n}|$ are basically two (even and odd) subsequences whose sum is a sequence, so $=|b_n|$ which is also $\epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2$. So if $|b_n|\lt\epsilon$ we know the function is convergent.

Comment: Not quite the correct idea. You don't need the triangle inequality. I added a proof of the $\implies$ direction as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $\implies$ direction. Note that you are given that

$$b_{2n} \to a, b_{2n+1} \to a$$

We show that it will follow that $b_n \to a$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $n_0$ such that $|b_{2n}-a| < \epsilon$ if $n \ge n_0$ and choose $n_1$ such that $|b_{2n+1}-a| < \epsilon$ if $n \geq n_1$.

Put $N:= \max\{n_0,n_1\}$. If $n \geq 2N+1$, then $|b_n-a| < \epsilon$.

Indeed, if $n$ is even then $n= 2k$ for some $k$. Since $n \geq 2n_0$, we have $k \geq n_0$ and thus $|b_{2k}-a| <\epsilon$. Similarly, one handles the case where $n$ is odd.

Your proof of the other direction is correct. A subsequence of a convergent sequence always converges to the same limit and thus the subsequence of terms with odd index and the subsequence of terms with even index have the same limit.

Comment: why $n\ge N$ would not suffice?

Comment: No, it wouldn't suffice. My proof uses that $n \geq 2N$.

Comment: Ah, I think I see why N won't do. But now I'm lost why 2N would suffice. If $n_1$ is 10. Then we need at lease $n=2*10+1$ for $|b_n-a|\lt\epsilon$ to converge. Hence $n\ge2N+1$? Unless I'm missing something again.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a mistake there! Nice catch. It is clear that you understood the proof I gave. I corrected the mistake.